# Why: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: php, http, curl, post, uri

I want to get user's Ticket through password and login. Authentication process is carried out with BASIC  scheme in HTTPHEADER.
However, I get error: no http resource was found that matches the request uri

```
$curl_ticket = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl_ticket, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'myURL/api/Auth',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Content-length: 0',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('login:password'),
    ],
]);
$ticket = curl_exec($curl_ticket);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl_ticket);
$error = curl_error($curl_ticket);
curl_close($curl_ticket);
```

Comment: Try adding a domain to the url `'http://localhost/myURL/api/Auth'`

Comment: @brombeer
My full url looks like: https://w01.hsc-copter.com/api/Auth